# How do I fix IronPDF's error "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Global\IronSoftwareDeploymentGlobal' is denied."

Tags: asp.net-core, ironpdf

We're using IronPDF to change a dynamic HTML string into a PDF. In localhost, dev and test environments, it works without a problem. However, in our QA environment, we get the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '?' threw an exception.

 ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Global\IronSoftwareDeploymentGlobal' is denied.

   at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew)

   at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name)

   at ?..cctor()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at ?.?[?]()

   at ?.?()
```

I do not believe it is a problem with the code because it works in some environments, so I have not provided code. It's an unauthorized access error, so I'm guessing something needs permissions, but I cannot find the Global\IronSoftwareDeploymentGlobal path anywhere.

Comment: Did you identify where the `unauthorized error` is being thrown ? What is exactly the changes between your the two environment? Please share additional details to investigate further as the problem is little foggy to get into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the path 'Global\IronSoftwareDeploymentGlobal' is denied.

This exception was seen in IronPdf 2021.11.4257 and was resolved in IronPdf 2021.12.4401.

Please [update IronPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/) to remove this issue.

https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/239-access-to-the-path-global-ironsoftwaredeploymentglobal-is-denied